# Length of a specific field, and showing the record in much easier way

Tags: bash, shell, unix

My goal is to find out the length of the second field and if the length is more than five characters, then I need to show the entire record using shell scripts/command.

```
echo "From the csv file"
cat latency.csv  |
while read line
do
        latency=`echo $line | cut -d"," -f2 | tr -d " "`
        length=$(echo ${#latency})
        if [ $length -gt 5 ]
        then
                echo $line
        fi
done
```

There is nothing wrong with my code, but being UNIX/Linux, I thought there should be a simpler way of doing such things.

Is there one such simpler method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'length($2)>5' file
```

this should work

**updated**

```
 awk -F, '{a=$0;gsub(/ /,"",$2);if(length($2)>5)print a}' file
```

Comment: Except the poster wants to ignore spaces in the fields, as indicated by the `tr -d " "`.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, there are spaces in the fields which I want to ignore. I can't cut the spaces in the output, but while doing the length, I need to remove the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '{
  t = $2
  gsub(/ /, x, t)
  if (length(t) > 5)
    print
  }' latency.csv
```

Or:

```
perl -F, -ane'
  print if 
    $F[1] =~ tr/ //dc > 5
  ' latency.csv
```